# Using Fermat's Little Theorem, find the least positive residue of $3^{999999999}\mod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm going through the problems in Rosen's Elementary Number Theory and am having some trouble with the this problem,

> Find the least positive residue of $3^{999999999}\mod 7$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fermat's Little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) says that

> If $p$ is a prime and $a \nmid p$, then $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p.$$

We can use this theorem to [reduce exponents](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/hausner/rsa.pdf), such as in the problem at hand. First, we should observe that the hypotheses of Fermat's Little Theorem are met. Namely,

$$7 \ \text{is prime and } 3 \nmid 7.$$

So we have that,

$$3^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7.$$

The exponent can therefore be reduced in the following manner,

$$3^{999999999} \equiv 3^{999999996} \cdot 3^3 \equiv \left( 3^6 \right)^{166666666} \cdot 3^3 \equiv 1^{166666666} \cdot 3^3 \equiv 1 \cdot 27 \equiv 6 \mod 7.$$

Comment: Why used the generalied case when in this cases $n$ is prime?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah, I'm not sure why I went immediately to the generalization.

Answer (score 4):

From FLT, $3^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7.$ Since $999999999 = 166666666 \times 6 + 3$ we have $$ 3^{999999999} \equiv 3^3\equiv 6.$$

Comment: FLT$\neq$ Fermat's last theorem, but the little one.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\, {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\ \color{#c00}{3^3\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, (\color{#c00}{3^3})^{333333333}\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^{333333333}\equiv -1$