# Finding a Residue using Fermat's Theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am currently working through an assignment and have almost solved the following problem.

> Use Fermat's Theorem to find the residue of $2^{1000} \,\text{mod}\, 59$.

Now I have stated that $2^{58}$ is congruent to $1 \,\text{mod}\, 59$, and broken the problem up into parts, beginning with $2^{986} * 2^{14}$, and then gone further until the first part equals $1$.

The problem is that no matter how I have tried manipulating things, I get stuck with $2^{14}$and I was under the impression the answer should be between $0$ and $58$?

I have been following the answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418909/using-fermats-little-theorem-find-the-least-positive-residue-of-3999999999) so far, but in that scenario it works out nicely with $3^3$ already being small.

Am I missing something obvious here, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, $2^{14}$ is $16384$. Now we can divide by $59$ and find the remainder. To do it on an ordinary calculator, divide by $59$. Mine says $277.6949153$. Subtract the integer part $277$, and multiply by $59$.I get $41$. Because of calculator roundoff, we might not get an integer, we might get something like $40.99997$, but it will still be clear that the answer ought to be $41$.

Comment: Yeah I did do that at first, but the question asks for Fermat's Theorem, and they seem pretty touchy if we add in extra things, so I wanted to avoid that if I could.

Comment: Your Fermat Theorem calculation tells us that $2^{1000}\equiv 2^{14}\pmod{59}$. All I was addressing was going the rest of the way, after we have reduced the exponent to $14$. But in this case since $2^6\equiv 5$, one can do the rest of the calculation in one's head.

Comment: It doesn't say "use only", in fact it is probably impossible to do it using just Fermat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break $2^{14} \equiv 2^{6} \cdot 2^{6} \cdot 2^{2} \equiv (5)(5)(4) \equiv 41 \pmod{59}$

Comment: So just to clarify, finding the largest multiple of 58 in 1000 and then splitting it from there is the right way to go about these problems?

Comment: Yes that's the best approach.